# Customize confirm box using TypeScript

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angular7

I would like to customize this ugly confirm box: 'localhost 4200 say..."

I’m working with Angular7 and have very little programming experience. There are a lot of JavaScript examples using sweetalert, jQuery etc.  but I need a Typescript one... Any idea how can I edit this confirm function to show my customize box?

// My Typescript file

```
deleteBook(_id: string, form: NgForm) {
     if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')) {
       this.bookService.deleteBook(_id)
         .subscribe(res => {
           this.getBooks();
           this.resetForm(form);

         });
     }
   }
```

// My html file

```
<a (click)="deleteBook(book._id, bookForm)" class="aColorRed"> delete </a>
```

Comment: This is not a [typescript] question, it's angular question. pls mod the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngx-bootstrap for this.

**In your HTML:**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Open modal</button>
    <br><br>
    <pre class="card card-block card-header">{{message}}</pre>
    <ng-template #template>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p>Do you want to confirm?</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="confirm()" >Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="decline()" >No</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

**In your component**

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-service-confirm-window',
  templateUrl: './service-confirm-window.html'
})
export class DemoModalServiceConfirmWindowComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  message: string;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {class: 'modal-sm'});
  }

  confirm(): void {
    this.message = 'Confirmed!';
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }

  decline(): void {
    this.message = 'Declined!';
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you mark the answer if it resolved your issue.Thanks